# block output of debugged program (gdb)

Tags: gdb

I have a program and want to debug it in gdb.

Will I see usual program output? How can I enable/disable this output, leaving only gdb messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can redirect output from within gdb:

```
(gdb) run > somefile.txt
```

will redirect standard output to somefile.txt. You can also specify a terminal to send output to:

```
(gdb) tty /dev/ttyb
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you will see all output from your program.

You can disable this by sending it off elsewhere. For example:

```
(gdb) run > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

**Ignore stdout and stderr**

```
run &>/dev/null
```

Analogous to the Bash syntax.

Tested on GDB 7.10.

Answer (score 2):

If you  just want to see the output of the program as you step through it without gdb's output, this script can be useful.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
delay=1 #seconds
lastTime=`stat --printf=%y "$file"`

while [ 1 ]
do
  thisTime=`stat --printf=%y "$file"`
  if [ "$thisTime" != "$lastTime" ]
  then
    clear
    cat "$file"
  fi
  lastTime="$thisTime"
  sleep $delay
done
```

lastTime="$thisTime"
  sleep $delay
done

Comment: Wat? Where is gdb? How to use this? I wanted just what I asked, start program in gdb, work wiht gdb, but not to see program's stderr and stdout.