# GDB print to file instead of stdout

Tags: redirect, printing, gdb

I am running GDB and want to examine one of those unfortunate god objects. It takes many pages (and I have a 24" monitor turned sideways!) to see the whole thing.

For ease of use, I'd like GDB to print the object to a file instead of the screen so that I can open it in vi and move around with ease.

With all of GDB's versatility, there must be a way to do this, right?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You need to enable logging:

```
(gdb) set logging on
```

Now GDB will log to `./gdb.txt`. You can tell it which file to use:

```
(gdb) set logging file my_god_object.log
```

And you can examine the current logging configuration:

```
(gdb) show logging
```

Comment: And if you want the output to go _only_ to the log file, use `set logging redirect on`.

Comment: Shouldn't we set `set logging file my_god_object.log` before `set logging on`?

Comment: This plus `tail -f` and `awk` was really helpful today.  Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

I've found that you can redirect the output from gdb to a file via the `run` command:

```
(gdb) run > outfile
```

Comment: That would be the output from the program being debugged, not the output from gdb itself. OP wanted to log gdb's own output.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388561/block-output-of-debugged-program-gdb

Comment: @thepaul but this is in fact very useful as I'm debugging a QT program that just trashes gdb's stdin with it's QDebug garbage

Comment: @rostamn739 oops, didn't help at all

Comment: ```run &> outfile``` is sometimes needed to capture the complete output. Noticed while using GoogleTest that all lines weren't getting added (unless the stderr was also redirected with &>)

Answer (score 22):

Extending on @qubodup's answer

```
gdb core.3599 -ex bt -ex quit |& tee backtrace.log
```

the `-ex` switch runs a gdb command. So the above loads the core file, runs `bt` command, then `quit` command. Output is written to `backtrace.log` and also on the screen.

Another useful gdb invocation (giving stacktrace with local variables from all threads) is

```
gdb core.3599 -ex 'thread apply all bt full' -ex quit
```

Comment: On some systems, you need to type `gdb -c core.3599 ...`

Comment: > gdb core.3599 -ex 'thread apply all bt full' -ex quit  
  
Add --batch to run without a prompt -eg  
    sudo gdb --batch core.3599 -ex 'thread apply all bt full' -ex quit > output.log

Answer (score 16):

From https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html:

> You may want to save the output of gdb commands to a file. There are several commands to control gdb's logging.
>
> ```
> set logging on
> ```
>
> Enable logging.
>
> ```
> set logging off
> ```
>
> Disable logging.
>
> ```
> set logging file file
> ```
>
> Change the name of the current logfile. The default logfile is gdb.txt.
>
> ```
> set logging overwrite [on|off]
> ```
>
> By default, gdb will append to the logfile. Set overwrite if you want set logging on to overwrite the logfile instead.
>
> ```
> set logging redirect [on|off]
> ```
>
> By default, gdb output will go to both the terminal and the logfile. Set redirect if you want output to go only to the log file.
>
> ```
> show logging
> ```
>
> Show the current values of the logging settings.

Comment: Copy paste of https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html without citation.

Answer (score 9):

A simple method to log gdb to a file while still seeing the output (which eases writing commands) is to use `tee`:

```
gdb command |& tee gdb.log
```

Comment: Note that one cannot use `tui enable` or `layout` commands in this mode. `gdb` says `Cannot enable the TUI when output is not a terminal`

Answer (score 3):

I had a backtrace that was so long (over 100k lines) that holding down the enter key was taking too long. I found a solution to that:

[Andreas Schneider's bt command](https://blog.cryptomilk.org/2010/12/23/gdb-backtrace-to-file/) writes a backtrace to file without any user interaction – just prefix your command with `bt` .

Here, I've turned it into a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ex=(
    -ex "run"
    -ex "set logging overwrite on" 
    -ex "set logging file gdb.bt" 
    -ex "set logging on" 
    -ex "set pagination off"
    -ex "handle SIG33 pass nostop noprint"
    -ex "echo backtrace:\n"
    -ex "backtrace full"
    -ex "echo \n\nregisters:\n"
    -ex "info registers"
    -ex "echo \n\ncurrent instructions:\n"
    -ex "x/16i \$pc"
    -ex "echo \n\nthreads backtrace:\n"
    -ex "thread apply all backtrace"
    -ex "set logging off"
    -ex "quit"
)
echo 0 | gdb -batch-silent "${ex[@]}" --args "$@"
```

Answer (score 3):

Redirection of a **gdb**'s command output to a file can be made by using Python (my version of **gdb** is **8.1.1**):

```
(gdb) python
>with open("/path/to/file/bt.txt", "w") as outfile:
> outfile.write(gdb.execute("bt", to_string=True))
>end
```

For convenience this functionality can be added as a command to gdb by adding into **.gdbinit**:

```
python
import argparse

class RedirOutput(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("rdr", gdb.COMMAND_USER, gdb.COMPLETE_COMMAND)

    def invoke(self, argstr, from_tty):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('command', nargs='+')
        parser.add_argument('-o', "--outfile", required=True, help="output file")

        nm = parser.parse_args(argstr.split())

        with open(nm.outfile, "w") as output_file:
            try:
                output_file.write(gdb.execute(' '.join(nm.command), to_string=True))
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))

RedirOutput()
end
```

**Variants of usage:**

```
### Inside gdb
(gdb) rdr info -o /absolute/path/info.txt
(gdb) rdr info registers eax -o ./eax.txt
(gdb) rdr bt -o ./bt.txt
```

**Note:** if saving in a file is needed for subsequent opening in **vim** or **less** for more convenient viewing and paging, then the "file step" is redundant, because gdb's output can be redirected right to these programs, see [redirection to **less**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66590807/2913477).

Answer (score 2):

Although there are many good answers here, I still have to post the only thing that worked for me:

```
[niko@my-laptop]# gdb MyBinary 2>&1 log.txt
```

This was the only way to get gdb **and** binary output into the same log.txt file, while also seeing it on the console.

**EDIT:**

**Caution:** Output seems to be partially not synced among the gdb output and the binary output. Can someone confirm? You might want to check whether your telnet/ssh client has a function to log the output that you see in your console.

Answer (score 2):

You've had multiple answers here. They are corrects. I just want to add a command that will help you to collect all the output at once. This really helpful when your collecting a huge backtrace. Before doing any logging configuration, do this:

```
(gdb)set height 0
```

I found it on this article: https://askaralikhan.blogspot.com/2016/05/gdb-all-threads-bt-to-file.html?showComment=1584614942454#c4584028195226351332