# Using less as gdb pager

Tags: gdb

I noticed that in GDB, when issuing commands with long output like `info variables`, the output is displayed one page at time, pressing `enter` to go down and `q` to quit.

Is it possible to replace the default pager with another one, such as `less`, so that I can navigate up and down, quitting, searching, etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to replace the default pager with another one

No: GDB doesn't call into external program to display the output, it simply *pauses* the output every screenfull (and you can make it not pause by `set height 0`).

In addtion to running inside `emacs`, you could also use `screen` or `tmux` (learning them will  generally help you in a lot of other situations), or ask GDB to log output (`set logging on`) and then search in `gdb.txt` with any `$PAGER` you want.

Comment: Perfect: I suspected it was something like this, but did not know about the height 0. I am already using `tmux`, so this is the best option! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Starting with version 9.1, GDB has a `pipe` command, so you can send a command's output to the pager of your choice. From the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Shell-Commands.html#index-pipe):

> pipe [*command*] | *shell_command*
>
> Executes *command* and sends its output to *shell_command*. Note that no space is needed around `|`. If no *command* is provided, the last command executed is repeated.

Comment: Any way to get GDB to apply styling when `pipe`'d?  So you can get colored output on things like `pipe info threads | less -SR`.

Answer (score 4):

run `gdb` inside of `emacs` and you should be able to use emacs' paging commands.

1. run emacs
2. type `M-x gdb` return (M stands for meta - alt key or option on Macs)
3. The Emacs message bar will now display the message:
   `Run gdb (like this): gdb`

More information is available here: http://tedlab.mit.edu/~dr/gdbintro.html

HTH

Answer (score 4):

you can put the following user-defined commands in ~/.gdbinit, then

```
% cat ~/.gdbinit
python import os
define less1
    python os.popen("less","w").write(gdb.execute("$arg0",to_string=True))
end

define less2
    python os.popen("less","w").write(gdb.execute("$arg0 $arg1",to_string=True))
end
...
% gdb
(gdb) less2 info var
...
(gdb) less1 disass
...
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
Error while executing Python code.`

Comment: Please add "python import os" in your .gdbinit first.

Comment: It looks like GDB 8.0 might have changed how `python` and `$arg<n>` interpolation inside a `define` work. Has anyone got this working in GDB 8?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit old thread, but I think it is worth to add. @yichun gave a very nice idea here, but to be more practical it can be extended to any number of arguments:

```
define less
    python import os
    python os.popen("less","w").write(gdb.execute(' '.join(["$arg{0}".format(i) for i in range(0, argc)]), to_string=True))
end
```

Then it can also woth adding exceptions handling and waiting for processes to terminate to avoid keyboard glitches and we have something like that:

```
% cat ~/.gdbinit
define less

python argc = $argc
python
import os
f = None
try:
    f = os.popen("less","w")
    f.write(gdb.execute(' '.join(["$arg{0}".format(i) for i in range(0, argc)]), to_string=True))
except Exception as e:
    if f:
        f.write(str(e))
    else:
        print (str(e))
finally:
    if f:
        f.close()

end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

In **gdb 8.1.1** this code in `.gdbinit` adds the required functionality:

```
python
import os

class Less(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("less", gdb.COMMAND_USER, gdb.COMPLETE_COMMAND)

    def invoke(self, argstr, from_tty):

        with os.popen("less","w") as pipe:
            try:
                pipe.write(gdb.execute(argstr, to_string=True))
            except Exception as e:
                pipe.write(str(e))

Less()
end
```

**Usage**

```
(gdb) less info breakpoints
(gdb) less backtrace
```

**Information:** [Commands In Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Commands-In-Python.html).