# how to redirect output of `backtrace` in GDB to a file?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'm debugging a big project to get understand how it works, by the way it developed in multi-thread way, so there were multiple backtraces, by using

```
thread apply all bt full
```

in GDB, you can get the full stack traces of every thread, is there a easy way to redirect these messages to a outer text file?

---

Duplicated, please refer to this thread please: [Gdb print to file instead of stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941158/gdb-print-to-file-instead-of-stdout)

Comment: Don't forget `set pagination no`