# Debugging janus gateway using gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, webrtc, janus-gateway

I am new to use janus gateway in webrtc. I have run the demo application in janus gateway. Now I want to run the janus application on gdb to test the debug information. How can I do this and get the debug information to a file. Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Following is the link to janus gateway docs. 
http://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/

Comment: First compile it with debugging enabled and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941158/gdb-print-to-file-instead-of-stdout should help

Answer (score 1):

You can set the debug level in the `janus.cfg` file ( `/etc/janus/janus.cfg`)  or at the launch of the Janus with by passing the option `--debug-level` after the `janus` command (`janus -d=1-7`) (0=disable debugging, 7=maximum debug level; default=4)