# VSCode C++ debug capture console output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am running VSCode in Ubuntu to debug a C++ program. Debugging a console app with GDB is working fine except I really want to capture the console log output to a file. I cannot see a way or option to do this. Is there any option to capture this console log output?

Comment: what console log? this is C++- not JS, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there does not seem to be a native feature to save the output of a VSCode terminal, maybe you can use in said terminal a command allowing you to save that session.

See for instance "[Gdb print to file instead of stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36821621/6309)"

```
gdb core.3599 -ex bt -ex quit |& tee backtrace.log
```

As mentioned, the output is written to `backtrace.log` and *also* on the screen.

As the [OP Andy Tomlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9927208/andy-tomlin) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807641/vscode-c-debug-capture-console-output/50814007?noredirect=1#comment88659625_50814007), this is not compatible with a debugger session.

> We solved the problem by just handling it inside the app and redirecting `cout` internally to a file.

Comment: As vscode is launching the application there is no opportunity to tee the output.

Comment: @AndyTomlin Sure, but could you launch the app from a VSCode regular terminal, just for testing?

Comment: We are running the debugger. We solved the problem by just handling it inside the app and redirecting cout internally to a file. Not very satisfying but a work around for now.

Comment: @AndyTomlin OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.