# using GDB with arguments

Tags: c, gdb, command-line-arguments

For a class assignment we needed to write a compiler.  This includes an optimizer portion.  In other words, we take in a file with some "code".  An output file is generated.  In the second step we take in the outputted code and remove any "dead" code and re-output to a second file.  I have some problems with the optimizer portion and would like to use gdb. But I can't get gdb to operate properly with the input and output files arguments.  The way we would normally run the optimizer is:

`./optimize <tinyL.out> optimized.out`

where tinyL.out is the file outputted in the first step and optimized.out is the file I want to output with the new optimized and compiled code.

I have searched Google for the solution and the tips I have found do not seem to work for my situation.  Most people seem to want to only accept an input file and not output a separate file as I need to do.

Any help is appreciated (of course)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a program with commandline arguments using GDB within a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121094/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-commandline-arguments-using-gdb-within-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. But since I'm not yet able to comment everywhere, I write this answer with a guess and edit/delete if necessary.

When GDB is started and before you start the program you wish to debug, set the arguments you want to use with `set args`.

A reference to the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb#Arguments).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do the file redirection within gdb.

```
gdb ./optimize
(gdb) run < tinyL.out > optimized.out
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2388594/5657035