# How can i stop VS Code from echoing the command used to invoke a compiled program

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, gdb

I compiled and ran a C++ program using the integrated Button in VS Code. In the terminal it output this and then the actual output of my program:

<sup>& 'c:\Users\david.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.17.5-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-mai1qwjv.bjt' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-dpfm03jr.uey' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-kvc5riii.2br' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-3xanv2jw.wnw' '--dbgExe=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'</sup>

Is there any way to disable this?

I already searched the terminal settings in VS Code but i didn´t find anything that could correspond to that.

I also found this question: [block output of debugged program (gdb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388561/block-output-of-debugged-program-gdb) but i didn´t understand it fully.

Comment: **NO**. And how do you expect VSC to start/debug your program, this **IS** the way VSC does it. it is a lot better that it does run your program compared to not running

Comment: When your program works how are you going to start it? How do you think the users of your program are going to start it?

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification.